# How to make my app to wait for txt files in a folder in Java?

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, jaxb, wait

I'm learning about Java and Spring Boot and I need to do an app to process txt files. So I have a folder and in this folder I receive txt files. The app will wait for the txt files in one folder and will put the processed txt files in another folder. Once an txt file is received in the specific folder, the app will process it and then it will wait for another txt file to process. I know how to do the business logic and how to export the txt files after process them, but how can I do this waiting process? Any feedback will be apreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using spring boot I would use their scheduling service to check for new files on a schedule. You have to add the `@EnableScheduling` tag to your configuration. Then define a method to run on the schedule.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60000)
public void checkForNewProductFiles() {
```

See more here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

Answer (score 0):

Checkout for spring integration which does exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Below is the sample code which listens remote location for any new files and process if any.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sftpInboundFlow() throws IOException {

    if (update.isClearLocalDir) {
        FileUtils.clearLocalDir(update.localPath);
    }

    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(
                    Sftp.inboundAdapter(sftpSessionFactory)
                            .preserveTimestamp(true)
                            .deleteRemoteFiles(true)
                            .regexFilter(update.filterExpr)
                            .localDirectory(new File(update.localPath))
                            .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
                            .remoteDirectory(update.remotePath),
                    e -> e.id("sftpInboundAdapter")
                            .autoStartup(true)
                            .poller(Pollers.fixedRate(update.pollingFrequency)
                                    .maxMessagesPerPoll(1)))
            .channel(updateFileChannel())
            .get();
}

@Bean
public DirectChannel updateFileChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow orderUpdateFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(updateFileChannel())
            .handle(fileProcessor, "handleUpdate")
            .get();
}
```

Refer https://spring.io/guides/gs/integration/

Refer [Spring Intergartion](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/index-single.html)